# access fields by column name in SqlAlchemy raw select

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
games = session.execute(statement=text('select game.id as id, * from game')).all()
for game in games:
  print(game['id'])
```

I get `tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str'.
How can I access the fields by column names and not by index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use dot-notation instead of subscript notation:

```
$ cat foo.py 
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

engine = db.create_engine(<redacted>)
with engine.connect() as session:
  games = session.execute(statement=text('select * from game')).all()
  for g in games:
    print(g.id)


$ python3.11 foo.py 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you want dictionary-style access you can use the [Row](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row)'s [_mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row._mapping) attribute:

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    res = conn.execute(text("""SELECT * FROM tbl"""))
    for row in res:
        print(row._mapping['id'])
```

If you want the row as an actual dictionary (`._mapping`'s return value is not a true `dict`) then use the [_asdict()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row._asdict) method:

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    res = conn.execute(text("""SELECT * FROM tbl"""))
    for row in res:
        row_as_dict = row._asdict()
        # Do something with the dict
```

---

Generally we should not use underscore-prefixed attributes of objects in Python as the underscore indicates that the attribute is private, but in the case of row attributes they are prefixed to prevent name-collisions with columns from the database.